# Calculated DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to calculated one of my columns on a datagridview using an expression, but I am having issues with the correct syntax.

Here is my code:

```
        'TotalSell
        Dim col11 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        col11.DataPropertyName = "TotalSell"
        col11.HeaderText = "TotalSell"
        col11.Name = "TotalSell"
        col11.ReadOnly = True
        col11.Visible = True
        col11.Width = 40
        col11.Expression = "[UnitSell]*[Qty]"

        DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col11)
```

It errors for the line "col11.Expression", Expression is not a member DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Can anyone help out with the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you sure col11.Expression is a property? Probably it is a method?

Answer (score 0):

You should set this property to a new column created on the underlying datatable before binding the table to the datasource of the DataGridView,

Something like this

```
Dim table = GetDataFromDB();
table.Columns.Add("TotalSell" typeof(decimal), "[UnitSell]*[Qty]")
DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```